# Creating items or updating items inside folder in sharepoint list in SPFX typescript using PNP or spghttp client

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, pnpjs

I was trying to creating an SPFX solution using React where on submit of form I am saving multiple items inside a folder in SharePoint list.

I understood how to create folder inside SharePoint list using PNP but not able to create items inside the created folder.

Below is the code for creating folder in SharePoint list.

```
let list = sp.web.lists.getByTitle('TestList');
return list.items
  .add({
    Title: 'Dummy',
    FileSystemObjectType: 1,
    ContentTypeId: '0x0120'
  })
  .then(({ item }) => {
    return item.update({
      Title: 'New Folder',
      FileLeafRef: 'New Folder' 
    });
  }).then((f) => {console.log("Folder created")})
```

It would be really helpful if anyone has any idea how to create, update get item inside folder in SharePoint list.

Comment: Check answer given at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264136/q-create-list-item-inside-folder-with-spfx

Comment: Could you please also let me know how to get items inside folder in sharepoint list using pnp js by using folder name?

Comment: Is above code working for you to create folder? To get items from folder, check [this](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/890).

Comment: Yes adding and get Item is working. Thank you very much. One doubt is like how to check if folder alredy exists and updating item inside any idea?

Comment: Great. I have summarized all the comments and added it as an answer below. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.
Regarding your question to check if folder exists and updating item, I will suggest you to create a new question and explain your requirements in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addValidateUpdateItemUsingPath` to create list items inside folder.

Sample code:

```
const listPath = `${webRelativePath}/Lists/ListUri`;

sp.site.rootWeb.lists.getById(ListId).addValidateUpdateItemUsingPath([
    { FieldName: 'Title', FieldValue: 'TestItem' }
], `${listPath}/FolderPath`).then(console.log);
```

To get items inside folder, you can try filtering on `FileDirRef` property like given in below reference.

Sample code:

```
import { sp } from '@pnp/sp';
const listUri = '/sites/site/Lists/list';
sp.web.getList(listUri).items
    .filter(`FileDirRef eq '${listUri}/SubFolder01'`)
    .get().then(console.log);
```

**Reference**: [Get All Items from a List subfolder](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/890)

Comment: could you please let me knowin case you find something like updating items already added in folder sharepoint list using PNP JS?

Comment: While updating SharePoint list item, you will need its item ID. If you have item ID with you then try using the [Update](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#update) method if it works.

Comment: FileDirRef is an issue incase there are more than 5000 items. Is there any other way around